# NullPointerException with radix sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I try to program radix sort, but I have NullPointerException when I run this code

```
public class ThreeRadixSort {

    public Queue getSortedData(Queue queue){
        Queue array[] = new Queue[10];

        for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){

        while(queue.front != null){
            Student student = queue.dequeue();

            if( i == 1) 
                array[(int)(student.id%10)].enqueue(student);
            else if( i == 2)
                array[(int)((student.id%100)/10)].enqueue(student);
            else    
                array[(int)(student.id/100)].enqueue(student);

        }

        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){

        while( array[j] != null && array[j].front != null)
            queue.enqueue(array[j].dequeue());
        }
        }   
        return queue;
    }
}
```

The Exception show when the implement reach to

```
    array[(int)(student.id%10)].enqueue(student);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when you initialize your array of `Queue`, each spot is initialized to null.  So right now, you are trying to call the `enqueue` method on `null`.  You need to loop through each position of the array and assign it a `new Queue()` or however you initialize those.

So for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = new Queue();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome - would you mind modding up / accepting this answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
 Queue array[] = new Queue[10]
```

only declares an array of queues. It does not allocate the queues itself.
you should initialize them like this:

```
 for(int i; i<10; i++)
 {
      array[i] = new Queue();
 }
```

p.s. by the way. Instead of relying on a magic number like '10' it's better practice to make it a constant and declare on the top of your program. Like such:

```
 const int numElements = 10;
```

Comment: I would tend to agree with your statement about magic numbers, except when the constant can never change - then I feel like it just decreases readability (since it suggests to the reader that it might change).  In this case, the only way his number of queues would change is if he implemented the algorithm in a  base other than 10, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I would tend to your idea ,danben